# Проблемы в работе Moodle

Tags: moodle

После установки все работало корректно, но примерно через неделю пропала возможность загрузки курсов. В окне загрузки просто вращается бублик и не чего не происходит. В журналах сервера ошибок нет. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]